# closeOnEscape in Dialog FrameWork PF

Tags: primefaces

In a `<p:dialog>` there is an attribute called `closeOnEscape="true"` which allow to close the dialog by pressing the esc key.

I didn't find any similar thing in Dialog FrameWork attributes, according to primefaces documentation.

Is there a way to achieve this using DF ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not supported yet, please create a request in issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Primefaces hotkey component: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/hotkey.xhtml

This component is a very convenient and helpful way to auto generate javascript which listens for "onkeyup" events.

```
<p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('myDialogName').hide();" />
```

Comment: It will always be a close same dialog by ESC.

Comment: @0x5a4d: unless you use a remoteCommand and from the serverside command you use the RequestContext to call a dynamic  PF('…').hide() where … is any dialog you want